# Looking for a quote from Johannes Bronkhorst

Tags: reference-request, rebirth

I recall, years ago, reading about Buddhist treatises on rebirth, composed some long time after the Buddhas death.

It was a very brief reference of Johannes Bronkhorst's, probably in a footnote. I've searched various of his big works looking for it, and numerous papers. If anyone happens across a likely candidate, would you please let me know?

It seemed to indicate there was a period in which one faction was trying to convince another that the Buddha taught rebirth. I'm interested in learning anything I can about how far back the debate that lives on today goes.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: hi Linda. The suttas, such as MN 95, refer to how the Buddha compared the Brahmin Pundits to a lineage of blind men. Scholars can be similar, often regurgitating the same often speculative ideas & accepted yet unsubstantiated histories. However, returning to fresh in-depth studies of root sources can be very helpful. While not exactly on the topic of Bronkhurst, you could consider running your ruler over this link: https://www.buddhismwithoutboundaries.com/dazz/Is_%E2%80%9Crebirth%E2%80%9D_a_misconception_of_the_Pali_suttas.pdf Regards

Comment: @Dhammadhatu. Spectacular bit of research, thanks. Will take me a while to go through it all, but I can already see how useful it will be. Who is the author?

Comment: Thank you for the kind words dear Linda. I am pleased you found it interesting. The author is here: https://www.buddhismwithoutboundaries.com/showthread.php?6671-Exploring-rebirth-in-the-Pali-suttas&p=84497#post84497

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a quote about disagreement between Buddhist schools on rebirth, but I found this 1998 lecture by Johannes Bronkhorst entitled "[Did the Buddha Believe in Karma and Rebirth?](http://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:bsz:16-jiabs-88691)".

Perhaps you're thinking about Pudgalavada.

From the [Atman (Buddhism)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_(Buddhism)) wikipedia article:

> According to Johannes Bronkhorst, it is possible that "original
> Buddhism did not deny the existence of the soul", even though a firm
> Buddhist tradition has maintained that the Buddha avoided talking
> about the soul or even denied its existence.

The linked footnote reads:

> Johannes Bronkhorst (1993). The Two Traditions of Meditation in
> Ancient India. Motilal Banarsidass. pp. 99 with footnote 12. ISBN
> 978-81-208-1114-0.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. But -- right -- not quite what I'm looking for.